# How to Auto Restart a 2010 MacBook Pro/High Sierra after Power Failure

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

I wonder how to make a 2010 Macbook Pro with High Sierra (10.13.6) restart when power adapter is plugged in.
"Energy Saver" panel shows no "Start up automatically after a power failure".
`sudo pmset -a acwake 1` doesn’t work. I tried a NVRAM reset.
`sudo nvram AutoBoot=%03` doesn’t work. `pmset -g cap`shows that `autorestart`is not an option.
I use the MBP as a music streamer (iTunes, Bit Perfect, "Remote" App on the iPhone, optical output). Battery is disconnected. I want the MBP to turn on if power is switched on by the amp - without touching the MBP.
Anyone any Idea? -Martin

Comment: something I do not understand, you say battery disconnected !how does it run without power

Comment: @Buscar웃 it runs on the power adapter. That's why he wants the MacBook to automatically perform a reboot, like iMacs do (if enabled) when disconnected from power. I suppose MacBooks don't have that option by default as they are expected not to suffer from sudden power loss because they usually have batteries in place..

Comment: @Buscar웃 Kevin Grabher Yeah. The amp is on the cabinet, the MBP is placed in the drawer. The MBP power adapter is connected to the amp. When I turn on the amp, the power connector is connected to power and the MBP should  turn on (Itunes is auto started). When the amp is turned off - well, there’s no battery, and the MBP suffers from sudden power loss ...

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem but I just might want to add that it is generally not a good way to power off a computer by just "plugging it out" instead of a proper shutdown. You might experience file/system corruption at some point.

Comment: I think you have to do that in the boot sector.

Comment: @Kevin Grabher I hope the system will be kind. I did this with a 2007 Macbook/10.6.8 for a couple of years without (visible) damage

Answer (score 1):

Try doing that in the boot sector.

Use Restore > Disk Utility > Terminal

[image]

```
pmset autorestart 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention: pmset autorestart 1 is no option on my system - I checked with pmset -g cap. Sorry!

Comment: @Martin do you have the `acwake`

Comment: I tried `sudo pmset -a acwake 1` - it’s in the list showed using `pmset -g cap`but didn’t work. I also tried a NVRAM reset.

Comment: @Martin can you publish your pmset -g cap list

Comment: It says: "Capabilities for AC Power: displaysleep - disksleep - sleep - womp - acwake - lidwake - halfdim - sms - ttyskeepawake - hibernatemode - hibernatefile"

Comment: @Martin while on power restart your Mac to make the changes permanent

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with not having battery at all `acwake (laptop only) wake the machine when the power source is changed, such as when AC power is removed and the machine switches to battery power, 1 to enable` so if you leave battery in and then cycle the AC

Comment: @Martin you do realize that without battery your Mac will cut down the CPU in half, it needs battery to operate at full CPU power

Comment: Buscar웃 I did a restart. I have to add that the battery is still in there; I plan to disconnect it when the auto restart works. Oh, I didn’t know that CPU is less powerful without battery. I think it will still be enough for iTunes. I will have a try. Thank you so much for your thinking.